# Proof: A closed subset of a compact space is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Let $X$ be a compact topological space and let $A\subseteq X$ be a closed set, then $A$ is compact

Proof: let $\{S_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ be a family of closed sets in $A$ such that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}S_\alpha=\emptyset$. For all $\alpha$, $S_\alpha$ is closed in $A$, and $A$ is closed in $X$, then $S_\alpha$ is closed in $X$, $X$ is compact; therefore there are $\alpha_1, \alpha_2,...,\alpha_n$ such that $\bigcap_{1\leq i \leq n}S_{\alpha_{i}}=\emptyset$

1. Why can we assume that there are "$\{S_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ be a family of closed sets in $A$ such that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}S_\alpha=\emptyset$. "?
2. Why if there are "$\alpha_1, \alpha_2,...,\alpha_n$ such that $\bigcap_{1\leq i \leq n}S_{\alpha_{i}}=\emptyset$" we can conclude that those are the same $S_{\alpha}$ that we had in $A$ as $A$ is "smaller" than $X$ or in other words they maybe $k$ such that $S_{\alpha_k}\in X$ but $S_{\alpha_k}\notin A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because, for instance, the family which consist of $\emptyset$ and only of that set is a family of closed sets with empty intersection.
2. Because we are assuming from the start that $\{S_\alpha\mid\alpha\in I\}$ is a family of subsets of $A$.

Comment: I know that an intersection of close sets is a close set, but can we say that a close set is a product of an intersection of close sets?

Comment: I don't see how you put products here.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos an old fashioned term for intersection is meant here...Kuratowski also wrote $A \cdot B$ for the intersection of two sets, e.g.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you, but then what is a product of an intersection?

Comment: He means that a closed subset of a closed set is again closed in the superset, because it is the intersection of two closed sets, I suppose. That's quite correct.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sure, that is correct.

Comment: Sorry for using the phrase product, I will rephrase it. can we say that any close set is an intersection of a set of closed sets?

Comment: Sure. If $C$ is a closed set, then $C$ is the intersection of all elements of $\{C\}$, which is a set of closed sets.

Answer (score 1):

The basic fact that the text relies on the following characterisation of compactness: (recall that a family of sets is said to be FIP (finite intersection property) if every finite subfamily of it has non-empty intersection).

> A space $X$ is compact iff every FIP family of closed sets of $X$ has non-empty intersection in $X$.

(equivalence 5 on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Equivalent_definitions) states as much, and it's easy to show using complements and de Morgan).

If now $C \subseteq X$ is closed and $X$ is compact, take any FIP family $\{F_i\mid  \in I\}$ in $C$. As $C$ is closed, all $F_i$ are also closed in $X$ (!) and still are FIP. So by compactness of $X$, the family has non-empty intersection and $C$ is thus compact. QED.

Your formulation goes via a contradiction which is unnecessary and inelegant IMO.